# We are getting a slew of requests from IE9 for /scanImageUrl

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, browser, request

The requests are ALL from Internet Exploder 9 with compatibility mode turned on. We know compatibility mod is on, because of the trident attribute being sent in the user agent string.

This just started recently.

These are legitimate users, not bots, we have determined that. And we cannot repro the issue.

Here is one new google search result, and it appears that others are having the same issue.
http://www.webmasterworld.com/webmaster/4560505.htm#msg4560681

Help appreciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: I need help with this as well. Unfortunately, the bureaucracy closes questions for being off-topic instead of moving them to where they are appropriate (Web Masters for instance).

Comment: so i added it there. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47044/we-are-getting-a-slew-of-requests-from-ie9-for-scanimageurl