# URL requests with [object] in place of parameter values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

We're seeing requests to our server with the literal [object] replacing the values where parameters should be.

For example: http://example.com/users/[object]

I've found some suggestions that it might be something to do with IE9 but we can't quite nail it down. See: http://www.webmasterworld.com/webmaster/4560505.htm

Has anyone else seen this behaviour? Have you managed to nail down what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but this seems like a duplicate of [We are getting a slew of requests from IE9 for /scanImageUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771399/we-are-getting-a-slew-of-requests-from-ie9-for-scanimageurl) which was closed as off-topic. Maybe there's a more appropriate SO sister site for web-development questions. Anyone have suggestions?